# How to specify background image with Thymeleaf?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm learning spring boot with thymeleaf. I've stored user object's profile image in the file system and  only the URL of the image is part of the User object persisted in the database.

 I've added the `name` and `dpurl` into the model, in order to access it from the template.

```
@GetMapping("/profile")
public String profileController(@AuthenticationPrincipal User activeUser, Model model) {
            model.addAttribute("name", activeUser.getName());
            model.addAttribute("dpurl", activeUser.getDpURL());
            return "profile";
        }
```

I'm able to access `name` from template using `th:text="${name}"`

 
However, I'm not able to specify background image using thymeleaf like this

```
<div id="dp-container" th:style="'background-image: url(' + @̣{dpurl} + ');'" >
```

this is resulting in error
 `Could not parse as expression: "'background-image: url(' + @̣{dpurl} + ');'"` 

Update
Changed it like this

```
<div id="dp-container"  th:style="'background-image:url(' + @{dpurl} + ');'">
```

Now I'm not getting any error but background image still not being displayed.
How to specify background-image using Thymeleaf?

Comment: #1 If you want to improve the readability use th:style="|background-image:url(@{dpurl});|"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It probably needs to look like this:

```
<div id="dp-container"  th:style="'background-image:url(' + ${dpurl} + ');'">
```

But it depends on what `dpurl` contains.  Do you really need to use `@{...}`? Then you should use `@{${dpurl}}`.

To debug this, you should be looking at the source.  it will reveal what your expressions are resolving too.

Comment: `dpurl` contains a fully qualified url of an image in the files system.. Is it possible to access disk files like that from a webapp? ..I created a simple static html page with only an `<img>` element and it's `src` attribute contained fully qualified url of an image on the disc, it worked, but when i moved it to `static`  directory` of webapp ,the image didn't show up?

Comment: You put the image in the static folder but you don't see the image. How does the generated style-attribute in the delivered html-page looks like?

Comment: @Flocke Everything works fine except image..I guess the problem is that, image is in a directory that is not part of the project structre..Can't hosted webpages access files in the local file system outside project direcotry?

Comment: @Arjun: Locally, yes! You can open nerby every single file from your local (windows) maschine in a browser on the same maschine, only depends on access-rights. But you can't serve that image to clients in the web because their browser have no access to that file.  ... Spring boot should definitly add the static folder to path. Thus, th:style"|background-image:url(${imgPath});|" should work if imgPath is something like "/image/myImage.jpg". I don't think you need @ here.

Comment: @Flocke  I completely forgot that, without the help of a controller, tomcat and spring boot only serve static contents from it's `static` and  `public` directories ...

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work:

```
<td  th:style="'background: url(/images/aws2.png)'" class="fluid hero-image" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you've got something more complex like needing to pass a variable into the url, you can try this:

```
<div id="profile_image" th:style="'background-image: url('+ @{'/view-profile-pic/' + ${result.profile_pic}} +');'"></div>
```

And in css, the image was displayed correctly with:

```
#profile_image {
margin: auto;
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
box-sizing: border-box;
border-radius: 100px;
background-size: cover; 
}
```

I stumbled upon this solution when I wanted to display profile pictures received from search results.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this too if none of the others work. Upload the image to some online store like a file sharing service or google drive and provide the link to the image as the url for your background-image property.

```
<div id="dp-container" style="background-image: url(Link to the image);" >
```